# Mejor perfomance en metodo en c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

vengo con una duda en cuanto a optimización de código, es viable dejar el código que detallo a continuación el cual hace uso de un procedimiento almacenado o lo convierto haciendo uso de `Entity Framework`

```
 public void Obtener_Presupuesto_Version_Dos(String sValue, DataGridView dataGridPre, TextBox subtotal, TextBox pordscsub, TextBox totdscsub,
     TextBox portarsub, TextBox tottarsub, TextBox total)
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Buscar_Presupuesto_Edicion", conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                SqlParameter paramCodRetorno = new SqlParameter("@CODPRE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)
                {
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                    Value = sValue
                };
                _ = command.Parameters.Add(paramCodRetorno);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    String pre_cod = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_COD"]);
                    String pre_cod_pac = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_COD_PAC"]);
                    String pre_nom_pac = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_NOM_PAC"]);
                    String pre_cod_odon = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_COD_ODON"]);
                    String pre_nom_odon = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_NOM_ODON"]);
                    String pre_rut = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_RUT"]);
                    String pre_den_pac = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_DEN_PAC"]);
                    String pre_pie_den = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_PIE_DEN"]);
                    String pre_tra_pac = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_TRA_PAC"]);
                    Double pre_val_pre = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_VAL_PRE"]);
                    Double pre_val_por = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_VAL_POR"]);
                    Double pre_val_des = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_VAL_DES"]);
                    Double pre_val_sub = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_VAL_SUB"]);
                    Double pre_val_por_dsc_sub = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_VAL_POR_DSC_SUB"]);
                    Double pre_val_tot_dsc_sub = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_VAL_TOT_DSC_SUB"]);
                    int pre_val_por_tar_sub = Convert.ToInt16(reader["PRE_VAL_POR_TAR_SUB"]);
                    Double pre_val_tot_tar_sub = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_VAL_TOT_TAR_SUB"]);
                    Double pre_val_tot = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_VAL_TOT"]);
                    int pre_id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["PRE_ID"]);
                    String pre_fec_ela = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_ELA_PRE"]);
                    String pre_fec_rea = Convert.ToString(reader["PRE_EST_REA"]);
                    _ = dataGridPre.Rows.Add(pre_cod, pre_cod_pac, pre_nom_pac, pre_cod_odon, pre_nom_odon, pre_rut, pre_den_pac, pre_pie_den,pre_tra_pac, pre_val_pre, pre_val_por, pre_val_des, pre_val_sub, pre_id, pre_fec_ela, pre_fec_rea);
                    subtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_sub);
                    pordscsub.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_por_dsc_sub);
                    totdscsub.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_tot_dsc_sub);
                    portarsub.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_por_tar_sub);
                    tottarsub.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_tot_tar_sub);
                    total.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_tot);
                }
                //dataGridPre.AllowUserToAddRows = false;                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

No se si veo necesario el uso de Entity Framework ya que se utiliza más para manipular tablas directamente que por procedures, quizás es buena opción optar por Dapper. Este último ORM es facil de montar y hacer uso de stored procedures. Te comparto código de como lo podrías hacer con dapper:

```
public class Presupuesto
{
    public string PreCod { get; set; }
    public string PreCodPac { get; set; }
    public string PreNomPac { get; set; }
    public string PreCodOdon { get; set; }
    public string PreNomOdon { get; set; }
    public string PreRut { get; set; }
    public string PreDenPac { get; set; }
    public string PrePieDen { get; set; }
    public string PreTraPac { get; set; }
    public double PreValPre { get; set; }
    public double PreValPor { get; set; }
    public double PreValDes { get; set; }
    public double PreValSub { get; set; }
    public double PreValPorDscSub { get; set; }
    public double PreValTotDscSub { get; set; }
    public int PreValPorTarSub { get; set; }
    public double PreValTotTarSub { get; set; }
    public double PreValTot { get; set; }
    public int PreId { get; set; }
    public string PreFecEla { get; set; }
    public string PreFecRea { get; set; }
}
```

Y luego en el método tendrías algo asi:

```
public void Obtener_Presupuesto_Version_Dos(string sValue, DataGridView dataGridPre, TextBox subtotal, TextBox pordscsub, TextBox totdscsub, TextBox portarsub, TextBox tottarsub, TextBox total)
{
    string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
    
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            
            List<Presupuesto> presupuestos = conn.Query<Presupuesto>("Buscar_Presupuesto_Edicion", new { CODPRE = sValue }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
            
            foreach (Presupuesto presupuesto in presupuestos)
            {
                dataGridPre.Rows.Add(
                    presupuesto.PreCod, presupuesto.PreCodPac, presupuesto.PreNomPac, presupuesto.PreCodOdon, presupuesto.PreNomOdon,
                    presupuesto.PreRut, presupuesto.PreDenPac, presupuesto.PrePieDen, presupuesto.PreTraPac, presupuesto.PreValPre,
                    presupuesto.PreValPor, presupuesto.PreValDes, presupuesto.PreValSub, presupuesto.PreId, presupuesto.PreFecEla,
                    presupuesto.PreFecRea
                );
                
                subtotal.Text = presupuesto.PreValSub.ToString();
                pordscsub.Text = presupuesto.PreValPorDscSub.ToString();
                totdscsub.Text = presupuesto.PreValTotDscSub.ToString();
                portarsub.Text = presupuesto.PreValPorTarSub.ToString();
                tottarsub.Text = presupuesto.PreValTotTarSub.ToString();
                total.Text = presupuesto.PreValTot.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

De esta manera queda mas prolijo, reutilizable y performante.